# How to change layout of PrimeFaces dataGrid

Tags: layout, primefaces, datagrid, jsf-2.2

I'm using PrimeFaces dataGrid component for showing my search results and it contains paginator with 10 results on each page. Is it possible to change dataGrid layout like below? It's like tile wall.

[image: itemlayout]

What is your suggestions? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try FluidGrid 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/fluidgrid/static.jsf

It is primefaces extension.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is  really good primefaces extension but I didn't understand how I can use it like my datagrid because I'm using paginator and lazy loading in it.

Comment: I would have tried that to. But if it does not work, there unfortunately is no solution. Unless maybe some separate plain jquery solution is applied after each page event